Chain many queries after first response in RTK Query
What is the proper way to chain queries if the 2nd query requires a parameter that is returned by the 1st?
const { data: posts } = useGetPostsQuery();

array of posts has parameter 'userId'. How to make queries for each item of posts, to take user's name by userId, and render posts with usernames?

You can refer to this question

You don't need to "chain" queries here. You can make a Post component that fetches the post data and renders it. Then map over posts and render Post for each post and pass the userId into it as a prop.

No, i need to take userId from each post, than make query to api for each post, it returns user data, then i take post and name of user from 2nd query and render my Component. Something like: Random User: post text...

userid comes from first api, right? so render your second component after fetching it

i take post with userId from first query, then i need send another request with this userid to take user's data from anoter endpoint. After first request i have array with 10 or more posts, each post have userId, but doesn't have another information about this user, so i need map posts and send 10 requests for each post to take user data.
